# Can't delete the space and backgroundcolor in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to build a newsletter with tables. div boxes aren't working to 100 % percent in every mail client.

As you can see, here

[image]

is this  what I prepared in Photoshop and I have some problems with the tables. How can I delete this space between the two images down and change the background color from the text ( in the middle of the pictures and the buttons ) to grey, if I'm giving it a new td ,then is nothing  working. It should look like the pic I uploaded. would be very nice if you can help me out.

```
<td width="29">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="291" valign="top">
                <a target="_blank" href="#">
                <img src="images/angebotbild1.jpg" style="display: block;" border="0" width="355" height="150"></a>

                <div style="margin-top: 3px;"></div>

                <font color="#778da7" face="Trebuchet, Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" style="font-size: 12px">
                    Wie gemacht für alle, die den etwas 
                    anderen Sommer 
                    erleben wollen: Diese Reise führt Sie zu den großen 
                    Metropolen und kleinen Städten des Baltikums. Jede 
                    davon wird Sie durch den Kontrast zwischen prunkvoller 
                    Architektur in den historischen Stadtzentren und der 
                    nachhaltigen in den neuen Arealen Bauweise faszinieren. 
                    Jeder Ort erzählt hier seine eigene, spannende 
                    Geschichte. Lassen Sie sich verzaubern.
                </font>
                <a  href="#" alt="Book now" target="_blank" style="color:#cc1f2f; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;float:right"><img border="0"  src="images/button.jpg" width="335" height="60" style="display:block;" border="0" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Z7D/3/)
here is the complete code,

Comment: I can't get the full answer at this point. I know that the top could be fixed by adding a star to the 600

 <table width="600*" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">

Comment: what  do u mean with star thats just a part of the newsletter not the whole one

Comment: <table width="600*"  ..

Comment: oh hold on , something happens now it looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/m2Z7D/4/   i have to mutch room to the left and the button is still with the space

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your style inside bottom `a` link from  `float:right`  to  `float:left`
2. change img tag inside `a` link, and make the image width 355 instead of 335.
   The bottom button is an image (button.jpg), you can only change it's background color by edit with photoshop, and don't forget to change its image size to 355px.

Next time please put your files in public area, we can not see what does it look right now and can only guess how it suppose to look like.

Comment: firstavel thank you. it works, but now i have the problem that there ist to much space on the left and right side. it should be on one line. thats how it should be http://i41.tinypic.com/28cggmx.jpg, and i whant to change the background color of the text not from the bottom. the room where the text is should bey lightgrey just like in the pic but thanx so far. i updatet the jsfiddle file http://jsfiddle.net/m2Z7D/5/   and thats how it looks like now http://i44.tinypic.com/qxpevl.png

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ASAP/wFkq2/
It's extremly bad using line break `<br/>` for layout, try to look up how to build a email layout http://templates.mailchimp.com/design/layout-and-purpose

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP answer seems to be covered already, here is an alternative output option for you for future use(s):

Rather than creating the tables yourself and manually working with the code, you can allow Photoshop to automate the process within the save for web option. This alternative allows you to save images as well as text so the text area you have in that section would simply be a slice type of No Image (Right Click with slice tool on a slice > Edit Slice Options). Now simply add the text right there within that selected slice.

When you save for web it will output a table with the images and text aligned properly. You can then clean up the text within the table with css to suit your needs.